# java process consuming memory higher than total RAM in top command but not visible in jconsole

Tags: linux, ram, jconsole

I have a server with docker container containing java processes. One of the processes is consuming memory more than 100%(117%) visible in top command.

I crosschecked using ps aux command but RSS and VSS values are even higher.

in free -g used memory is lesser.

When I checked in our jconsole memory is under control as given in java_opts max heap value.

Can someone suggest me do I need to panic or it is some expected condition

Comment: jconsole is only showing heap -- that's only a subset of the JVM's total memory usage. It doesn't count stack, and last I knew (which was a long time ago) it also didn't include the memory allocated to classloaders, and several other varieties of JVM internal uses.

Comment: That said -- you only need to panic if the system is swapping. Zero swap is used, so you have no reason whatsoever to panic.

Comment: Honestly, I would call most of this better suited to [unix.se] than Stack Overflow. It's not a question about coding, it's a question about system administration.

Comment: For example: [How is JVM memory usage calculated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460987/how-is-jvm-memory-usage-calculated); [Correctly determining memory usage in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34795/correctly-determining-memory-usage-in-linux)

Comment: thanks @charlesduffy but how did you find that zero swap is being used?

Comment: Swap used is zero in both `free` and `top` screenshots.

Comment: You can also run `vmstat 1` -- if the system is swapping you'll see the `si` and `so` columns nonzero.

Comment: added pmap -x command output in question. Can you please help me to understand what does anon mean and why anon is using 200 GB deleted memory

Comment: anon just means it isn't backed by a file with a name. Has no name == anonymous.

Comment: "deleted" doesn't in this context mean the _memory_ is deleted. It means the _backing file_ is deleted. So the program mmap'd a file, making a region of virtual memory backed by that file, and then deleted the file so the operating system can clean it up as soon as the program exits.

Comment: Doing this for heap does smell a bit like an application trying to ensure enough virtual memory is available for it to use as much as it wants, even if the system doesn't have as much proper swap available as intended.

Comment: And no, I'm not going to answer your question here, because as I previously stated, it's off-topic here.